# constructor for my class doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, list, constructor

I have the following ArrayIntList class with constructors defined as below. In the last constructor, I want to have boolean, which if true, instantiates a new object with that particular element in it. If set to false, it should just instantiate a new object with that many capacity. kindly look at the client code for what I mean here.  it works when boolean is true.

Class FILE:

```
public class ArrayIntList {
    private int[] elementData; // list of integers
    private int size;          // current number of elements in the list

    public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

    // post: constructs an empty list of default capacity
    public ArrayIntList() {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

    // pre : capacity >= 0 (throws IllegalArgumentException if not)
    // post: constructs an empty list with the given capacity
    public ArrayIntList(int capacity) {
        if (capacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity: " + capacity);
        }
        elementData = new int[capacity];
        size = 0;
    }

    //takes input list and adds to arrayIntList
    public ArrayIntList(int[] elements) {
      this(Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY,elements.length*2));
      for (int n: elements){
         this.add(n);
      }
    }

    //creates an arrayIntlist with data of element
    public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {
      this();
      if (notCapacity) {
         add(element);
      }
   //returns the totalCapacity NOT SIZE
    public int getCapacity() {
  return elementData.length;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class ArrayIntListExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new list and add some things to it.
        ArrayIntList list = new ArrayIntList();

        //*** here is my question about ****//
        ArrayIntList list1 = new ArrayIntList(2, false);//should give [] with capacity of two
        ArrayIntList list2 = new ArrayIntList(2, true);//should give [2] 
        //*** ****************************** ****//
        int[] array={2,3,4,5};
        ArrayIntList list3 = new ArrayIntList(array);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
        System.out.println("list = " + list);
        System.out.println("list1 = " + list1);
        System.out.println("list2 = " + list2);
        System.out.println("list2 = " + list3);
        System.out.println("capacity of list1" + list1.getCapacity());//prints 100 but it must be 2
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any code that would make that happen.

Comment: What is the problem?  Your constructor code looks fine (other than the fact that you are missing a `}`, which I assume to be a typo)...

Comment: What's happening with your constructors that you're not expecting?

Comment: What does your `add` method look like?

Comment: *I want to have boolean, which if true, instantiates a new object with that particular element in it. If set to false, it should just instantiate a new object with that many capacity.* You mean the `int element` parameter can be the element to add or the capacity to initialize the array?

Comment: If the answer to Luiggi's question is yes, then you have a **very** smelly design...

Comment: Also, there is a **huge** difference between the capacity of your array (array.length) and its current size (number of current elements in the array that has been initialized).

Comment: Adding a boolean parameter that is effectively superfluous, just to resolve ambiguity in the constructor (due to two of them having a lone `int` parameter) is not a very good design. Furthermore, you now have two ways to do the same thing.

Comment: There is no problem with code, but the constructor is not behaving as I intend it to. for eg, `ArrayIntList=new ArrayIntList(2, false);` should return a object with capacity of 2 elements. but `ArrayIntList=new ArrayIntList(2, true);` will return a object with one element which is 2. the former is not working, it returns empty object with 100 capacity while later works fine. I have mentioned in the `System.out.printlns`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I know there is a difference between capacity and size, but thats not my point of question here.My question is about how to.have an effective implementation, where I could initialize different constructors depending on the need of client.

Comment: @user1988876,  I would recommend using static factory methods for the "initialize with one element" use case.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

To want it to behave the way you want, I imagine you want to pass `element` to the constructor with the lone `int` parameter:

```
public ArrayIntList(int element, boolean notCapacity) {
    this(element);
    if (notCapacity) {
         add(element);
    }
}
```

Previously you were simply calling `this()`, which initializes the array with the default capacity. If you step through your code manually or with a debugger, you can see this happening.

There are other problems with your design, however. Aside from an unwieldy and confusing interface/API (through your constructors), there is also a difference between the capacity of your array (i.e., the total number of elements it can hold) and its size (i.e., the number of elements in the array currently).

**EDIT**

One of the reasons why your API is confusing is that you have the following scenario:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Constructor            | int | boolean | Behavior
-----------------------+-----+---------+---------------------------
(element)              |  2  |    x    | Array with capacity 2
(element, notCapacity) |  2  |  true   | Array with one element (2)
(element, notCapacity) |  2  |  false  | Array with capacity 2
-----------------------+-----+---------+---------------------------
```

- You have two ways of doing the same thing.
- You have an `boolean` argument that is given a negative name. It's easier to figure out the meaning of "capacity is false" than "notCapacity is false".
- You introduced a feature with limited value (initializing an array with one element of arbitrary value) while introducing inconsistency and confusion. Essentially the only point that `notCapacity` serves is to distinguish the two behaviors that you want (initializing with capacity vs. initializing with one element of arbitrary value).
- `element` has two, *very different* meanings: capacity vs. single element to be added to the array.
- Changing the `false` to `true` is enough to invoke wildly-different behavior from the constructor.
- Booleans in constructors are generally opaque and are of limited value. From seeing an invocation like `new ArrayIntList(5, true)`, is the intent obvious?

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you kindly comment why this is confusing or the constructor is smelly. I know there is difference between capacity and size of array, but how does that affect here. it is taken care in the rest of the code (which I have not pasted here) that ensuresCapacity when I add new element to it.

Comment: @user1988876 - Your design smells because you have a constructor that takes an int that could potentially mean two different things.  You should let the signature of the constructor define what it does.  In other words: "_the constructor that takes an int as a parameter uses the int as a capacity_... **OR** _the construtor that takes an int as a paramter uses the int as the initial element_." The int argument shouldn't have two different meanings depending on the value of some random boolean that you add to your constructor...

Comment: Great point about naming booleans: you should always avoid using terns like _not_ and _never_ in the names of boolean variables.  Otherwise things get confusing when you start dealing with double negatives...

Comment: Thanks Jahroy, how does this sound. constructor(int) and constructor(boolean, int) instead of constructor(int, boolean), is this also a bad style?

Comment: @user1988876 - So... You're going to just add a boolean to one of your constructors for the sole purpose of distinguishing the purpose of the int parameter?  Again, this seems like a bad approach.  What's wrong with the static factory method suggested by tster?  What's wrong with adding an element _after_ invoking the constructor?  What's wrong with passing an array of size one when you only want one element in the initial array?

Comment: ... and why do you even need this class to begin with? Why aren't you just using generics like the rest of the world?  If you want an ArrayList of ints, just use this:  `List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: ofcourse, there are other options. but I am in the learning curve, so it would be a good practice for me to write my own class. Now, I have a learned a bit as how to use constructors. Thanks!

Comment: @user1988876 - Cool.  Glad we could help.  You'll learn a much more usefull lesson if you study generics rather than implementing your own ArrayList.  Generics were introduced to eliminate the need for the code you're trying to write.

Comment: @user1988876 - Another thing worth learning: you should upvote the answers you find helpful and "_choose_" the answer that solved your problem by clicking the "_checkmark_" next to the answer (I guess you already know about the latter)

Comment: @jahroy,  While I would never let this code exist in production, I think for someone learning programming and data structures, it is a fine exercise to implement your own array list.

Comment: @tster - You're right.  I definitely should not discourage folks from learning on their own by playing around with stuff like this.  Point well taken.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at your constructor:

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {
  this();
  if (notCapacity) {
     add(element);
  }
}
```

Now lets look at this line:

```
this();
```

This line will call your constructor with no arguments.  That constructor looks like this:

```
public ArrayIntList() {
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}
```

So this will call the constructor which takes a capacity and it will pass DEFAULT_CAPACITY to it.   So adding some comments to the original:

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {

  this(); // initializes this object with a capacity of 100 and no elements

  if (notCapacity) {
     add(element); // if notCapacity is true, add the element
  }
}
```

As you can see, nowhere do you actually use the "element" variable if notCapacity is false (meaning it should be the capacity).

A very simple fix for this could be:

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {

  this(notCapacity ? DEFAULT_CAPACITY : element);

  if (notCapacity) {
     add(element);
  }
}
```

However, I think a better design would be to not have this constructor at all and instead provide the following static methods:

```
public static ArrayIntList createWithElement(int element) {
    ArrayIntList ret = new ArrayIntList();
    ret.add(element);
    return ret;
}
```

Then the caller has a clean and clear method to call to create a list with 1 element.

Comment: neat!. I like the createWithElement method. that might be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I think your API is confusing..

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean startElement) {
  this(startElement ? 1 : element);
  if (startElement) {
     add(element);
  }
}
```

I think you should remove this constructor and instead let users do `new ArrayIntList(new int[] { 2 })` if they want a list with a specific element in.

Comment: This is a possible solution but IMO depicts a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow through the code it is clear why the behavior is happening.

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {
  this();
  if (notCapacity) {
     add(element);
  }
}
```

This method will create a new Array of `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` and if its false it simply finishes the method and returns without anything else done.

The easiest solution would simply to add an else statement like this:

```
public ArrayIntList(int element,boolean notCapacity) {
  this();
  if (notCapacity) {
     add(element);
  } else {
     elementData = new int[element];
  }
}
```

Although, I would strongly suggest you rethink your class structure.